# how to use "NA" as string

Tags: r, na

I have one csv file in which one column is character-type. Few values of that variable are NA (string). But when I am reading csv file in R using read.csv(),  the "NA" strings are stored as NA. How can I fix it?

Comment: What does the csv file use to indicate missing values?

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem you facing. Please provide a MWE

Comment: @Pierre Lafortune, they are just blank in csv file

Comment: Blank can mean `" "` or `""` to new users. Whichever it is, add that to jeremy's answer as `na.strings=" "` or `na.strings=""`.

Comment: yeah it is a god idea thanks

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `na.strings` argument in `read.csv`:

```
read.csv("myfile.csv", na.strings = "NNN")
```

Comment: It works, but what does na.strings do? Is it replacing blank strings by "NNN"??

Comment: you need to tell `read.csv` how you handled blank data. The default is "NA", so you can change it to anything other than NA so that your data will be read. If you did use something instead of NA for missing values, change "NNN" to that.