# How to clear data in R (.CSV file)

Tags: r

I'm playing with a .csv file that has some "unknown" values that I have to clear in R. For example, column A has variables "yes", "no", and "unknown"

How can I get rid of the "unknown" variables using R code.

Comment: `read.csv` has a parameter named `na.strings` which you should set to "unknown`.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide a [reproducible question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so we can see some sample data. Other good ref links include https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Please read them, then come back and edit your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use "NA" as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33126182/how-to-use-na-as-string)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I got your questions you try to define Cellvalues that are "unknown" as an NA in your data frame. You can do this by setting the `na.string` in your `read.csv()` function.

```
df <- read.csv(file, na.strings = "unknown")
```

and that's it! Now you should have a new data frame that declares "unknown" as NA.